# Android Кастомное уведомление с кнопками

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Я хочу сделать кастомное уведомление с кнопками, но не знаю как заставить систему реагировать на нажатия. Точнее на нажатия должен реагировать сервис, который будет отвечать за проигрывание музыки. У меня есть xml уведомления:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TestRadio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Название песни" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPlayPause"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStop"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`ImageView` c id `@+id/imgPlayPause` и `@+id/imgStop` выступают в качестве кнопок. Первая кнопка будет меняться(play/stop) и уведомление не должно исчезать. А вторая будет отключать плеер и удалять уведомление.

Уведомление создается в сервисе, вот таким образом:

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_player);
    Intent intentPlayPause = new Intent(context, MediaPlayerService.class);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
    intentPlayPause.putExtra("button", "play");

    PendingIntent piPlayPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentPlayPause, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgPlayPause, piPlayPause);

    Intent intentStop = new Intent(context, MediaPlayerService.class);
    intentStop.putExtra(BUTTON_EXTRA_NAME, STOP_BUTTON_EXTRA);
    PendingIntent piStop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentStop, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgStop, piStop);

    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();

    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```

В сервисе создаю BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("radio", "Service Created");
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int button = intent.getIntExtra("button", -1);
            // здесь будет код, которые что-то делает
        }
    };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(getPackageName());
    registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
}
```

В итоге, ничего не получилось, в broadcastReceiver ничего не приходит, как мне исправит код, чтобы мая задумка заработала?